# Transaction not starting unless I do modification

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, transactions

I'm having an issue where my transaction doesn't truly seem to be starting unless I issue a command that appears to be transaction worthy (the last part is conjecture).

Below I have a method decorated with the @Transaction attribute, it's public, it's being called via the spring proxy.  I'm connecting to SQL Server, using Microsoft's JDBC driver version 4.2.  And getting an app lock, if I try and get the app lock before doing something that's transaction worth the transaction doesn't appear to start.  I'm guessing this based on the returned error code (-999) which is consistent with not being in a transaction.

This code works perfectly fine in my other project, but there we are doing more than just grabbing an app lock.

#### Here's the method (Ignore the fact that this would just lose the app lock right after fetching it)

```
@Transactional
public Boolean getAppLock(String lockString, Integer timeoutMilliseconds) {
    try {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        int result = session.doReturningWork(connection -> {
            int execResult = -1;

            // Works if I add this line
            // connection.prepareStatement("insert into foo (baz) values('bar')").execute();

            // This line works also, which is stupid, cause it doesn't even update anything
            // connection.prepareStatement("update foo set baz = baz where id = 1231241").execute();
            try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("declare @i int; exec @i = sp_getapplock ?,?,?,?; select @i;")) {

                statement.setString(1, lockString);
                statement.setString(2, "Exclusive");
                statement.setString(3, "Transaction");
                Integer timeout = timeoutMilliseconds == null ? 0 : timeoutMilliseconds;
                statement.setInt(4, timeout);

                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    resultSet.next();

                    // Complains about not being in a transaction, unless
                    // I have a random statement that seems transaction worthy
                    execResult = resultSet.getInt(1);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.error("Failed getting the result set from the app lock", ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Error executing statement sp_getapplock", ex);
            }
            return execResult;
        });

       // see return codes here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), 0+ is good, < 0 is bad

        return result >= 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a driver or a spring thing, I'm leaning toward driver thing.